# How can i put images in a listView?

Tags: android, xml, image, listview

I have a `ListView` but I can´t put images on it. 
The error is in `Activity_listView` at `holder.image.setImageDrawable(datos[position].getImage());`

The error message is

```
The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable 
for the arguments (ImageView)
```

Any idea for solve this?

Activity (Activity_listView):

```
package com.simarro.asteroids;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity_listView extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lstOpciones;
    ImageView asteroid = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_asteroid);
    private puntuacion[] datos = new puntuacion[] {
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Pepito Dominguez", "15489"),
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Pedro Martínez", "16598"),
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Paco Perez", "16332"),
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Rosana Fernandez", "18792"),
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Paco Jones", "960") };

    class AdaptadorTitulares extends ArrayAdapter<puntuacion> {

        Activity context;

        AdaptadorTitulares(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.puntuacion, datos);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View item = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (item == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.puntuacion, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image=(ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.img_asteroid);
                holder.jugador = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.LblJugador);
                holder.puntuacion = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.LblPuntuacion);

                item.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
            }

            holder.image.setImageDrawable(datos[position].getImage());
            holder.jugador.setText(datos[position].getJugador());
            holder.puntuacion.setText(datos[position].getPuntuacion());

            return (item);
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView jugador;
        TextView puntuacion;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        AdaptadorTitulares adaptador = new AdaptadorTitulares(this);

        lstOpciones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LstOpciones);

        //¡FUUUUUUUUU-SIÓN!
        lstOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The xml of content for layout with listView (puntuacion.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_asteroid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/asteroid" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LblJugador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LblPuntuacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</GridLayout>
```

The layout where is the listView (listView.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/LstOpciones" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The class for get values (Puntuacion)

```
package com.simarro.asteroids;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class puntuacion
{
    private ImageView image;
    private String jugador;
    private String puntuacion;

    public puntuacion(ImageView img, String tit, String sub){
        image=img;
        puntuacion = sub;
        jugador = tit;
    }

    public ImageView getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public String getJugador(){
        return jugador;
    }

    public String getPuntuacion(){
        return puntuacion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning `ImageView` in `getImage()`, return a `Drawable` and change it to

```
public Drawable getImage() {
    return image.getDrawable();
}
```

[getDrawable() Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable())

As the error says, the method `setImageDrawable()` takes a `Drawable` type but you are passing it an `ImageView`

Comment: Then, in the instance of puntuacion in Activity_listView, instead of asteroid, what type of format shall i use? A string such "drawable/asteroid" for access to image?

Comment: In Activity_listView i have an instance of puntuacion. The first parameter is actually an ImageView. When change the first parameter of the contructor in puntuacion.java form ImageView to Drawable, the instance of this need as first parameter a Drawable type. 
    
    ImageView asteroid = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_asteroid);
    private puntuacion[] datos = new puntuacion[] {
            new puntuacion(asteroid,"Pepito Dominguez", "15489"),
 
The idea is later, subsitute asteroid to some Drawable. How will be the Drawable? Sorry, my english is horrible.

Comment: It depends where you would be getting the `drawable` from. Right now, you should be able to do, `getDrawable(R.drawable.asteroid)` assuming you have a `Context` or are in the `Activity` when you use that code. [getDrawable Resource Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int))